# Python Serial Port PermissionError 13

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

serial.serialutil.SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, '�ý��ۿ� ������ ��ġ�� �۵����� �ʽ��ϴ�.', None, 31)

The code works well without any error when i first plugin the usb port but when I run the code more than once, it causes this error. Is this because the port isn't closed?

```
import serial
import time

ser = None  # Initialize ser

try:
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port="COM4",  # Update this to the serial port of your device
        baudrate=9600,  # Update this according to your device's settings
        timeout=1,
        stopbits=1,
    )

    # Check if the serial port is open
    if ser.isOpen():
        print("Serial port is open")
    else:
        print("Error opening serial port")
        exit()

    # Send a SCPI command to query the voltage
    ser.write(b"VOLT 7\n")

    # Give the device some time to respond
    time.sleep(1)

    # Read the response
    response = ser.readline().decode().strip()
    print(f"Voltage: {response}")

finally:
    if ser is not None:  # Check if ser is not None before attempting to close it
        ser.close()
```

this is my code

I've already installed CH340 driver. I need to keep on replugging the usb port when i run the code and it's quite annoying

Comment: Are you able to read the response on your first run of the program?

Comment: yeah i can 

Serial port is open
Voltage: 4.989

now i need to restart my laptop after i run the code lol why is this happening? i'm currently using windows 11 and i'm wondering if this is causing the problem